# username is currently used by process

Tags: centos, systemd, security, users, usermod

I am trying to change the home directory of a user. using

`usermod ravishshankar --home /var/www/domainname/public_html/` but get

`usermod: user username is currently used by process 1378`
I try to `kill pid 1378` but get `bash: kill: pid: arguments must be process or job IDs`

I tried `pkill -STOP -u user` but still get process 8009 in user by the user.

Comment: Is the user logged into the system?

Comment: negative.  One of my software automatically makes a user account in CentOS when I configure a new user in the software.  I deleted the user from the software but it still looks like the process is being used.

Comment: If the user isn't logged in, then `pkill -u username` and then run the `usermod` command.

Comment: I ran the commands but now a new pid is showing up as currently in use for user.  Is there a way I can log the user out directly?

Comment: Then stop the software and then run the commands.

Comment: that is above my paygrade atm.

Comment: `SIGSTOP` pauses a process: the process will still exist.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you get that output.

`kill pid` will give you that error message, while `kill 1378` will just kill the process (if you are authorized to do that). If that fails contact the user, or `kill -9 1378`.

And as ctrl-alt-delor remarked: SIGSTOP will pause the process, not kill it.

If a new process is created every time that you kill the process, you may want to look at the parent process (PPID in the `ps -ef` output). That is the most likely suspect that creates the new processes (unless ppid==1; then you need to investigate further)

Answer (score -1):

Processes were coming from one of the softwares.  So I made a webmaster account instead of the user account.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an answer. I any case it does not tell me what was wrong, or how to fix it. If you were to come back in a year, with the same problem, then would this help you?